# Plotly dropdown menu using column values as buttons

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I have a dataset, available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/YouCook21/AskToTheWebExamples/main/PlotlyDropdown.csv), which I would like to transform in a plotly plot with a custom drop-down menu.

My goal is to plot in a combined Scatter-Bar plot four values: `chrPos` (x-axis) and `depth_total, depth_5 and depth_3` (all on the y-axis) depending on the Feature column (which should be selected in the drop-down menu).
For example (where Cluster equals to Feature)

[image]

Do you have any clues on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# groupby the id
grps = list(df.groupby('centroid'))
# create a start and end step because we have three graphs for each id
start=0
end=3

buttons = []
figs = go.Figure()
# iterate over the groupby object
for idx,v in enumerate(grps):
    # use the centroid as the name of each graph
    name = f'{v[0]}'
    # set the visibility of each graph on selection
    visible = [False] * len(grp)*3
    visible[start:end] = [True]*3
    # update the start/end values
    start+=3
    end+=3
    # create your graph for each id
    fig = px.scatter(v[1], x='chrPos', y='depth_total')
    fig.add_bar(x=v[1]['chrPos'], y=v[1]['depth_3'], name='depth_3')
    fig.add_bar(x=v[1]['chrPos'], y=v[1]['depth_5'], name='depth_5')
    
    # set the visibility for the first three traces as the default
    
    if idx == 0:
        fig.data[0].visible = True
        fig.data[1].visible = True
        fig.data[2].visible = True
    else:
        fig.data[0].visible = False
        fig.data[1].visible = False
        fig.data[2].visible = False
    # add all your traces to the empty go.Figure
    figs.add_traces(fig.data)
    # append your dropdowns
    buttons.append(dict(label=name,
                        method="update",
                        args=[{"visible": visible},
                              {"title":f"Cluster n: {name}"}]))


updatemenus = [{'active': 0, "buttons": buttons, 'showactive': True}]
figs.update_layout(title=f'Cluster n: {grps[0][0]}', title_x=0.5, updatemenus=updatemenus)
figs.show()
```

[image]

[image]